# Flutter Firebase Auth Password Reset

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm trying to utilize the Firebase Auth sendPasswordResetEmail() call in my app.

In my auth file I declare the following:

```
 Future<void> sendPasswordResetEmail(String email) async {
    return _firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
  }
```

I pass the Auth to my a form widget that takes in this password and has the following onPressed function once I submit.

```
onPressed: () async {
    var response = await checkEmail();
    setState(() {
        this._emailValidator = response;
    });
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
        _formKey.currentState.save();
        try {
            await widget.auth
                .sendPasswordResetEmail(_email);
        } catch (e) {
            print(e);
        }
    }

},
```

I get the following console message after running it with a proper email:

"Tried calling: sendPasswordResetEmail("test@email.com")" Note: I used a real email for this.

I've set up the Firebase email template system but have not received any email. Does anyone know how I can further troubleshoot this or why my email is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured this out. I was not correctly passing the auth down from my auth file to the new file. As such, the method was being called on null, resulting in NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Could you possibly post the updated code to help others, thanks

Comment: @MichaelTolsma The above did work for me once I properly passed the Auth to the parameter of the widget. I previously wasn't passing the auth so it defaulted to null and created an error.

Answer (score -2):

pass your email to **sendPasswordResetEmail**

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: "test@.com").then((_) {
  toast("link has been sent to your email for password reset");
}).catchError((error) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => ErrorLog(text: error.message.toString()),
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This code is not syntactically valid and is not easily readable. I tried editing it myself to clean it up but was unsuccessful. Please [edit] your answer to [use code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and ensure that the code is both valid and well-indented. Also, please provide a little bit more context about how this answers the question, not just code. Note this question was already answered by the original asker over three years ago, so ideally, newer answers will expand on that to give extra useful help for those who find this question later.